# issued certificated has expired

Tags: home-directory, certificates, etc

I have download the code from GitHub and tried to build the project, but receive the following error:

```
issued certificate expired
```

The same project already exists on the system and no error is thrown.

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please, do not paste images for text data.

Comment: ok, noted. with thanks

Comment: Do you have your distribution updated? Currently kernel.org certificate looks fine for me.

Comment: Also do you use a proxy?

Comment: Not using Proxy